# Get reference to a Javascript Object from the Object name alone?

Tags: javascript, object

In javascript, Suppose I have a string called, `str = "document"`. How do I get the Object, Document which references it from the string name?

So what I would like to have is, take the string and get the reference to the Object, with the string name in the current closure.

`str = "window";` I would need the reference to the Window Object here.

Is there a dynamic way to get these references?

```
function getObject(str){
/* logic */

} 

getObject('window'); // returns [object Window]
getObject('document'); // returns [object HTMLDocument]
```

**Use Case:**
 I'm trying to fuzz a few stuff which comes from an array of strings. Here is what am trying to do. Would be great if you guys could tell me the best way to do this.

```
function hook(Obj, prop, newValue) {
    console.log(Obj, typeof Obj, prop);
        Object.defineProperty(Obj, prop, {
            'get': function () {
                return newValue;
            }
        });     
}

function test(Obj, prop) {
    var before = Obj[prop];
    hook(Obj, prop, 'xyz);
    var after = Obj[prop];

    if( before == after){
        alert(Obj + '.
        '+ prop +'
        Not Changed ');
    } else {
        alert(Obj + '.
        '+ prop +'
        Changed ');
    }
}

var data = [['document', 'domain'], ['window.document', 'location'], ['location', 'href']];
var i=0;
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    test(data[i][0], data[i][1]);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really make much sense, you can use bracket notation, as in `object[property]`, but the way you're explaining this it seems like you're trying to do something really weird ?

Comment: My first thought on this question is always that it is a XY problem. With proper design you should minimize your need to having to identify variables by their name to an absolute minimum. It is often used as a replacement for proper usage of arrays, for example.

Comment: Well, yeah ! I'm trying to fuzz a few stuff which comes from an array of strings. Here is what am trying to do. Would be great if you guys could tell me the best way to do this.


`function test(Obj,prop){
 var before = Obj[prop];
 hook(Obj, prop, 'xyz);
 var after = Obj[prop];

 if( before == after){
  alert(Obj + ' . '+ prop +' Not Changed');
 } else {
  alert(Obj + ' . '+ prop +' Changed');
 }
}

var data = [[document, 'domain'], [window.document, 'location'], [location, 'href']];
var i=0;
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
 test(data[i][0], data[i][1]);
}
`

Comment: I've added the real use case to the question.

Comment: sorry to keep asking, but why do you want to do it? Redefining important globals like these might not be a good idea. And fyi, the code breaks in Google Chrome (`href` cannot be redefined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object is a global one, then you can do it like this -

```
window['your-window-object'];
```

If it a property of another object, then you can do it like this -

```
obj['property-name'];
```

In every cases, you need to know the scope of the variable.

Example -

```
var doc = window['document'];  // gives you the document object
var obj = {
    prop1: 1;
    prop2: 2
}

var propValue = obj['prop1']; // gives you 1
```

For local variables, you might be tempted to use `eval`, but you should almost always it. For more information, just [google](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=eval+is+evil) it.

Comment: … and if it's just a local variable, `return eval('someVariable');` will work, **but** it should really never be used (eval is evil). In fact, this whole "get element by stringified name" should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks guys. Was just thinking, why wouldn't `this[str]` work?

Comment: @Skeptical: depends on what `this` represents and where it's used. If you are using `this` in a function which is called without `new`, then `this` will just represent the global `window` object. If you call that function with `new`, then `this['str']` will work as you expect.

Comment: @SayemAhmed So I think, this is what I want. `this[str]' 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You can obtain the reference by using

```
function getObject(str)
{
    console.log(this[str]);
}
```

Comment: OP asked for "current scope".